# Compare strings on iPhone fails?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, string

I'm trying to compare two strings with each other on the iphone, but the IF statement is always false. Here's my code:

```
NSLog([[UIDevice currentDevice]uniqueIdentifier]);
if ([[[UIDevice currentDevice]uniqueIdentifier] compare:[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] valueForKey:@"id"]] == NSOrderedSame) {
    //OK
    NSLog("Do stuff if equal");
} else {
    // Not OK
    NSLog("Do stuff if not equal");
}
```

The output is always

```
*** UDID *** (<- my device's UDID)
Do stuff if not equal
```

What am I doing wrong?

Thanks!
Yvan

Comment: Sure they're the same? Do an `NSLog()` on both and make sure.

Comment: Yes, because I previously stored the UDID in that "id" value.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using `stringForKey:` instead of `valueForKey:`, and `isEqualToString:` instead of `compare: ... == NSOrderedSame`.

Comment: Using isEqualToString: instead of compare: is unlikely to fix things; the main difference is that compare: does a (non-literal) Unicode string comparison which is slower but "correct".

Comment: I know, the fix was in changing `valueForKey:` to `stringForKey:`, the `isEqualToString:` instead of `compare:` was just because I think it's better/easier to use that in this case.